# biofilm model scales

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I have a question about the meaning of biofilm modelling scales:

Are they microscopic, mesoscopic and macroscopic.

Microscopic means individual bacteria

macroscopic means large number of concentration

and mesoscopic means the structure of biofilm.

If there is any mistake please correct me.

Thank you

Comment: I'd have thought it rather depends on the context in which the phrase is used. Could you elaborate? Is it a *large* bioreactor or a petri dish?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I am using mathematical models to model bacterial biofilm. However, I am required to write about biofilm modelling scales and to be honest I ve read several papers and I am not sure if my conclusion were correct.

Comment: Just like in math, in biology you have to define your terms. "Modeling scales" are whatever someone defines them to be, within the context their definition is used. Two papers can use the same word to mean something different if they want. For your writing, you'll have to cite the actual literature relevant to your field, not an answer on StackExchange.

Comment: I am not going to cite StackExchange. Just I wanted to clarify my understanding to the concept.